# SVG trouble in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, text, inkscape

I am having some issues using some SVGs that I have created in Inkscape. I am trying to use them in QGIS but they're not displayed properly. 
This: [image: http://i.imgur.com/BuxMWeO.png] is how the SVG looks like in Inkscape and how it should look on the map. This:[image: http://i.imgur.com/qoIFsJm.png] is how QGIS "sees" it.

I am having similar issues with other SVGs. I would also like to mention that this issue only occurs on SVGs that contain text. To be more precise, the text is the element that is not displayed properly. There was this very simple SVG; a red, thick circle with a "V" inside of it. In Inkscape, it looked good. In QGIS, the "V" would not show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can try to convert your text object to path (in Inkscape): Path -> Object to Path ?

Comment: I did try that. It didn't work, or I don't know how to use that option properly.

I took the long road and started building the letters. It's not a huge task but it annoyed me that I couldn't simply use the text tool.

Comment: A workaround could be to use svg without text then in QGIS add the letters as symbol layer, also latest qgis version as some dynamic svg feature you may have a look at how at how text are handled ther...

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with SVGs if they are not square. They may post to the map OK, but not display correctly in the menu. Your green square should be fine, but the text forms a rectangle, which may cause a problem. Can you add blank lines above and below, or make the text box square, and see if that helps?